# How to find the equation of the normal line to the surface S

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

How to find the equation of the normal line to the surface $S$: 
$$f(u,v)=(2u-v,u^2+v^2,u^3-v^3)$$
at the point $M(3,5,7)$? Could someone post the complete solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiki:

> If a (possibly non-flat) surface $S$ is parameterized by a system of
>   curvilinear coordinates $x(s, t)$, with $s$ and $t$ real variables,
>   then a normal is given by the cross product of the partial derivatives
>   $${\partial \mathbf{x} \over \partial s}\times {\partial \mathbf{x}
>  \over \partial t}$$

$$\frac{\partial f} {\partial u}=(2,2u,3u^2)$$
$$\frac{\partial f} {\partial v}=(-1,2v,-3v^2)$$

The cross product is:

$$(-6 u^2 v-6 u v^2, -3 u^2+6 v^2, 2 u+4 v)$$

Since the point is $(3,5,7)$ and is in the surface it must satisfy:

$$2u-v=3$$
$$u^2+v^2=5$$
$$u^3-v^3=7$$

Which solution is $u=2$ and $v=1$.

So the normal is $(-36,-6,8)$ so the equation of the line is:

$$p(t)=(3,5,7)+t\cdot (-36,-6,8)$$

Comment: Thank you. Could you please post the entire solution, because I get stuck after finding the cross product...

Comment: @Ashley see my edit please

Comment: Thank you for your time. It really helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

Given that the surface is presented by the equation

$f(u, v) = (2u - v, u^2 + v^2, u^3 - v^3), \tag{1}$

we have the two tangent vector fields to the surface:

$f_u = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial u} = (2, 2u, 3u^2) \tag{2}$

and

$f_v = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial v} = (-1, 2v, -3v^2). \tag{3}$

These vector fields are in fact linearly independent for all $u, v \in \Bbb R$ except at $u = v = 0$, as may be seen by calculating their cross product $f_u \times f_v$:

$f_u \times f_v = (-6(uv^2 + u^2v), 3(2v^2 - u^2), 2(2v + u)); \tag{4}$

inspecting (4) we see that $f_u \times f_v = 0$ implies the third or $z$-component equation becomes

$2(2v + u) = 0, \tag{5}$

or

$u = -2v; \tag{6}$

inserting this into the equation for the second or $y$-component yields

$3(-2v^2) = 0, \tag{7}$

forcing

$v = 0, \tag{8}$

and now using (6) we see that $u = 0$ as well.  Thus at all parameter points such that $(u, v) \ne (0, 0)$ we have $f_u \times f_v \ne 0$ as well; $f_u$ and $f_v$ are thus linearly independent except at $(0, 0)$.  We can find the parameter values $u, v$ such that

$f(u, v) = (3, 5, 7) \tag{9}$

from (1) by setting

$2u - v = 3, \tag{10}$

or

$v = 2u - 3, \tag{11}$

implying

$v^2 = 4u^2 - 12u + 9; \tag{12}$

inserting this into the $y$-component equation $u^2 + v^2 = 5$ yields

$4u^2 - 12u + 9 + u^2 = 5, \tag{13}$

or

$5u^2 - 12u + 4 = 0; \tag{14}$

applying the quadratic formula to (14) we obtain

$u = \dfrac{12 \pm \sqrt{144 - 80}}{10} = \dfrac{12 \pm 8}{10} = 2, \dfrac{2}{5}. \tag{15}$

Using these values of $u$ in (10) we obtain

$(u, v) = (2, 1) \; \text{and} (u, v) = (\dfrac{2}{5}, -\dfrac{11}{5}) \tag{16}$

as possible solutions.  It is easily checked that of these possibilities, only $(u, v) = (2, 1)$ satisfies $u^3 - v^3 = 7$; hence there is precisely one set of parameter values mapping onto $(3, 5, 7)$, *viz.* $(2, 1)$, and from (4) we find

$f_u \times f_v(2, 1) = (-36, -6, 8) \ne 0.  \tag{17}$

If $(x, y, z)$ is any point lying on the line normal to the surface at $(3, 5, 7)$ then the vector $(x, y, z) - (3, 5, 7)$ must be collinear with $f_u \times f_v$; thus for some $t \in \Bbb R$ we must have

$(x, y, z) - (3, 5, 7) = tf_u \times f_v(2, 1) = t(-36, -6, 8), \tag{18}$

or

$(x, y, z) = (-36t + 3,  -6t + 5, 8t + 7 ). \tag{19}$

(19) is the equation of the requisite normal line, and it is unique since $(2, 1)$ is the only point in $uv$-space with $f(u, v) = (3, 5, 7)$.

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***